# ploting circle in matlab map figure with scircleg

Tags: matlab

I want to plot a circle on a map figure.
I tried the axesm function and then the scircleg but although the mouse clicks worked the coordinates don’t pass and the following message appears

Attempt to execute SCRIPT message as a function:

c:\did\zmap\zmap\src\message.m

Error in scircleg (line 124)

```
       warning(message('map:scircleg:emptyLATPTS'))
```

Any help is welcome

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you create any function or varibable that called "message"? It can confuse Matlab..

Comment: The map figure was created by the zmap software packege which uses the message function.  I am trying to build a function inside the zmap.  Do you have any knowlege about the zmap software.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to add circles on a plot for indicating something on an existing figure, you can use:

```
hold on
plot(100,200,'o');
```

This adds a small circle at point `(100,200)`.